# Upgrading sonarqube from 4.5.4 to 6.7.1

Tags: sonarqube

I am planning to upgrade sonarqube from 4.5.4 (LTS) to 6.7.1 (LTS). Will it be possible to do a direct upgrade from 4.5.4 to 6.7.1 being both are LTS ?? Please suggest if I have to do a step upgrade by first upgrading it to 5.6.7 (LTS) and then later to 6.7.1

Answer (score 1):

As you will read in the ["Upgrading" documentation](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/upgrading.html), you can't do a direct upgrade from 4.5 LTS to 6.7 LTS. You will indeed need to upgrade first to 5.6 LTS.

Obviously, you can definitely do those 2 upgrades in a row.

Comment: Thanks. I will upgrade it to 5.6.7 and then later to 6.7.1